# Fuzzy String Matching using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have a training dataset for eg.

```
Letter    Word
A         Apple
B         Bat
C         Cat
D         Dog
E         Elephant
```

and I need to check the dataframe such as

```
AD    Apple Dog
AE    Applet Elephant
DC    Dog Cow
EB    Elephant Bag
AED   Apple Elephant Dog  
D     Door                
ABC   All Bat Cat
```

the instances `AD,AE,EB` are almost accurate (Apple and Applet are considered closer to each other, similar for Bat and Bag) but `DC` doesn't match.

Output Required:

```
Letters    Words               Status
AD         Apple Dog           Accept
AE         Applet Elephant     Accept
DC         Dog Cow             Reject
EB         Elephant Bag        Accept
AED        Apple Elephant Dog  Accept
D          Door                Reject
ABC        All Bat Cat         Accept
```

`ABC` accepted because 2 of 3 words match.

The words accepted need to be matched 70% (Fuzzy Match). yet, threshold subject to change.
How can I find these matches using Python.

Comment: Facing issues in framing the code. Nothing fruitful from the trials.

Comment: Can I assume if I have 2 letters (AD), I always have 2 and only 2 words (Apple Dog) (not 3, not 1) separated by space?

Comment: It can be variable.

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: So 2 letters -> 2 words, 1 letter -> 1 word, 3 letters -> 3 words. You always have 1:1.

Comment: Yes it always is 1:1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`thefuzz`](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) to solve your problem:

```
# Python env: pip install thefuzz
# Conda env: conda install thefuzz
from thefuzz import fuzz

THRESHOLD = 70

df2['Others'] = (df2['Letters'].agg(list).explode().reset_index()
                     .merge(df1, left_on='Letters', right_on='Letter')
                     .groupby('index')['Word'].agg(' '.join))

df2['Ratio'] = df2.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x['Words'], x['Others']), axis=1)
df2['Status'] = np.where(df2['Ratio'] > THRESHOLD, 'Accept', 'Reject')
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
  Letters               Words              Others  Ratio  Status
0      AD           Apple Dog           Apple Dog    100  Accept
1      AE     Applet Elephant      Apple Elephant     97  Accept
2      DC             Dog Cow             Dog Cat     71  Accept
3      EB        Elephant Bag        Elephant Bat     92  Accept
4     AED  Apple Elephant Dog  Apple Dog Elephant     78  Accept
5       D                Door                 Dog     57  Reject
6     ABC         All Bat Cat       Apple Cat Bat     67  Reject
```

Comment: How can the code modify if ratio isn't 1:1

Comment: @spd. In fact it doesn't matter. I created the `Others` column by exploding the `Letters` column. So for `DC` I extracted `Dog` and `Cat` from your first dataframe and compare it to `Dog Cow`.

Comment: Works. Thanks. Just another thing, if i make first dataframe as a combination of letters for eg.    ````AE as Apple Elephant````    ````AD as Apple Dog```` , how can it be done.

Comment: I need to check whole ```Letters``` string in dataframe 2 with ```Letter``` string in dataframe 1 and compare those words with each other to find the fuzz ratio.

Comment: If you have AE and EZ in your first dataframe and in your second, you have AEZ in your second, what should be the result?

Comment: Is another column mentioning ```Matching with two``` and ratio of ```EZ``` is higher possible? (For eg.)
If both are same then mentioning both if same row and different columns.